# PQ=-QP matrix what about P and Q

Tags: matrices

Actually I want relationship of trace of matrix P and Q but it's very hard to find matrix which satisfies this relation so please help to give example of matrix P and Q .

Comment: If you want an example you might consider the pauli matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices

Comment: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ works.

Comment: Actually is it correct to handle these types of problem by using example or is there is another way for dealing these kinds of problems as it sometimes become very difficult for thinking example which satisfies these conditions.

Comment: By using these examples I don't get the answer because in answer tr(P)=-tr(Q) but I always get the trace 0.so now what can I do please help

Comment: That depends. (Counter)examples are enough if you want to show that some specific property doesn't always hold. However, if you want to show that something always holds, then examples are good for illustration purposes and for searching for a pattern you can use to prove the general case.

Comment: Take $P=I$ and $Q=0$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(P)=n\neq 0$.

Comment: This is interesting since tr(P) != - tr(Q) in this case. Taniya are there some conditions you are missing like invertability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[We have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product):
$$
tr (AB)= tr (BA)
$$
so, if $AB=-BA$ we have ( by linearity of the trace):
$$
tr (AB)=tr (-AB)=-tr(AB) \quad \rightarrow \quad tr(AB)=0
$$